# Android база данных и сервер

Tags: android, sql, база-данных, firebase, клиент-сервер

Пишу приложение, суть которой заключается, что есть два входа,

1 - как студент

у студента будут лекции и контрольные вопросы, по которым потом в базу должны записаться кол-во набранных баллов.

2 - как преподаватель

у преподавателя список студентов и их набранные балы в виде таблицы

Вопрос какой сервер или базу использовать для регистрации студентов и добавление их в базу для получения таблицы как я описал выше. думал использовать firebase , но времени мало для поиска и изучения каждой базы или сервера, поэтому может вы подскажите что лучше использовать.

Comment: Ну я думаю проще mysql ничего нет.  Я так понимаю она у вас будет удаленной где то на сервере. Покупаете самый простой шаред хостинг за 5 баксов, там уже будет установлена phpmyadmin c MySql. Но придется все равно писать серверный код который будет обрабатывать ваши запросы и взаимодействовать с бд.

Comment: а мне кажется проще firebase нет ничего))

Comment: Если нет собственного сервера, придется использовать firebase. Если свой сервер есть, нужно будет написать API для взаимодействия с БД. Подключаться к БД из приложения, минуя API не рекомендую, чревато потерей БД.